# How do I get only part of my mongo document from inside my Meteor helper?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a document with an array of transactions. I'm trying to render a receipt template with the correct transaction's data. I just moved my subdocument into an array and I need to convert these helpers to reflect the change, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Here is my js file snippet.

```
Template.Gift.helpers({
  displayReceipt: function () {
    var transaction_guid = Session.get('transaction_guid');
    var transaction_status = this.recurring.transactions[transaction_guid].status;
    return (transaction_status === 'succeeded');
  }
});
```

And here is my html file snippet.

```
<div class="Receipt">
    {{#if displayReceipt}}
        {{> Receipt}}
    {{else}}
    {{/if}}
</div>
```

How can I change this to pull the correct transaction from the array?

Here is what my object looked like originally.

```
"transactions": {
    "TX1234": {
        "guid": "TX1234",
        "amount": 102,
        "email_sent": false,
        "status": "succeeded"
    },
    "TX1235": {
        "guid": "TX1235",
        "amount": 102,
        "email_sent": true,
        "status": "failed"
    }
}
```

Here is the new array style

```
transactions: [
    {
        "guid": "TX1234",
        "amount": 102,
        "email_sent": false,
        "status": "succeeded"
    },
    {
        "guid": "TX1235",
        "amount": 102,
        "email_sent": true,
        "status": "failed"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're accessing doesn't look like a Mongo (Minimongo) instance. It looks like you've pulled the `transactions` directly into a Javascript object, which seems to defeat the purpose of using Minimongo.

Anyway, this would be the query you'd use, if the transaction was in Minimongo:

```
var item = SomeCollection.findOne({"transactions.guid": transaction_guid});
var transaction = _.findWhere(item.transactions, { guid: transaction_guid });
```

The query returns the document with that whole array, because [Meteor doesn't support](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/fieldspecifiers) MongoDB's [`$elemMatch` projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) yet. So you'd have to filter for the right element yourself, as above. I'm using underscore's [`findWhere`](http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere) function in this example.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about Minimongo. I am using the session variable which Iron:router sets up from the URL param. The way I'm using it I do still see it acting reactively. 

Thanks, this works well.